# Why does Java string comparison with "==" work in some cases despite being different objects?

Tags: java

I have been told in a Java course at my university that I should never compare Java strings with the `==` operator, because it checks if two strings are the same object instead of checking if they have the same characters.

However, on the day of the exam, I am presented with the following code:

```java
if ("String".toString() == "String") 
  System.out.println("The same");
else
  System.out.println("Not the same");
```

I thought the result was going to be "Not the same", because `"String".toString()` and `"String"` are not the same object.

However, the console prints "The same"!. ¿How does string comparison with `==` actually work?

Comment: Did you read the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#toString())? `toString` returns the same object.

Comment: But I thought the "String" on the left and the "String" on the right were different objects anyways.

Comment: Because they *aren't* different objects, of course.

Comment: Here is actual reason why two string objects have the same references [How and where does String literals in Java stored in the memory](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-and-where-does-string-literals-in-java-stored-in-the-memory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at `String`'s `toString()` you'll see that it returns `this` (i.e. the same `String` instance on which it was executed):

```
/**
 * This object (which is already a string!) is itself returned.
 *
 * @return  the string itself.
 */
public String toString() {
    return this;
}
```

Therefore

```
"String".toString() == "String"
```

is equivalent to

```
"String" == "String"
```

which returns `true`, since both are `String` literals having the same value, so they are the same object.

A `String` literal is automatically added to the `String` pool, so all the places in the source code where you write the same `String` literal (such as "String") will return the same object from the `String` pool.